# How to hook Grails before resolve dependency

Tags: grails

In my code, Grails depends on another Maven project, I want to compile and install the maven project before Grails resolve dependency, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

use `scripts/_Events.groovy`:

```
eventCompileStart = {
  projectCompiler.srcDirectories << "${path}/${to}/${your}/${project}".toString()
}
```

Comment: CompileStart event triggered after resolve dependency. You can see that if you run grails application